# Multiple config.xml files for cordova

Tags: cordova

I am building a Cordova application that I am allowing different clients to brand.  I was wondering if there was a way to have a default config.xml, and then have second file that overrides the default with the branded values.  There are quite a few values I need to override, however some of the more obvious are :

- The id and version attributes of widget
- name
- description
- author
- icon (how would I override multiple of the same tag?)
- splash

If there is not a Cordova way of doing this, is there a linux tool that I could use for this purpose that would output my single config.xml file?

Comment: Cannot help. Looking for a solution myself. In the end it probably boils down to have small script that copies/merges client config files to/with `config.xml` and then run cordova with that config file. The client config file contains the paths to the client specific images, name and description. A simple node.js script could merge the two XML files via XSLT.

Comment: Did you find a solution? or did you just end up writing the script

Comment: I wrote the script

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to actually create a separate project for each instance of your application.

Here is how I would solve this:

1.Create a template for the `config.xml` file.

2.Create a `www` folder (containing the files of your application) in the same directory where you will create the `project_folders` for each instance of the application.

3.Create new instances of the application `cordova create...`

4.In each instance copy the template of `config.xml` over the existing one and modify for the specific instance.

5.Either copy the `www` folder from the directory above the `project_root` into it, or remove the `www` folder from the `project_root` and create a symlink to the `www` folder in the directory above the `project_root`.

Now you have separate instances of your application, all sharing the same `www` contents but with custom `config.xml` files.

Example Directory Structure:

```
App_Name
  \config.xml
  \www
  \{project_instance_1}
    \{config replaced}
    \www -> ../www
  \{project_instance_2}
    \{config replaced}
    \www -> ../www
```

Comment: I currently am using a separate project for each branded application, however if I want to add/update a global config option, I have to edit every config.xml and be very careful not to miss any.  My goal here is to have one master config file and then a second that has only the configurations for that brand instead of having to maintain many full config files.

Comment: That sounds very complex. Wonder why the Cordova CLI does not contain an argument to specify the `config.xml` to use. That would make it easy to just have a config file for each client.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `xlst` file to update the specific property on the `config.xml`. For example I have two bundles id (one for testing and the original). So I need a different `<widget id="<ID>">` for each.

My folder structure is:

```
App_Name
  \config.xml
  \configs
    \original
      \parser.xslt
    \test
      \parser.xslt
```

And each parser have its specific `id`, like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:widget="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="widget:widget/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="'TEST_BUNDLE'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I can do a simple unix command `xsltproc` to parse/change the file

`xsltproc configs/test/parser.xslt ./config.xml > output_config.xml`

Notice that the output file needs to be different from the original, after that you can `mv` the output to replace the `config`.

Hope it helps,

Cheers!